# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.0.1:rpm (default-cli) on project inv-project

Tags: java, maven, rpm-maven-plugin

I am getting the error below while creating an RPM of my Maven Project.

I am able to package the Jar successfully but RPM creation is failing.

**Note:** I am trying on Windows 7

```
[WARNING] operable program or batch file.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 42.696 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-10-08T15:06:40+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/228M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.0.1:rpm (default-cli) on project inv_project: RPM query for default vendor returned: '1' executing 'cmd.exe /X /C "rpm -E %{_host_vendor}"' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.0.1:rpm (default-cli) on project inv_project: RPM query for default vendor returned: '1' executing 'cmd.exe /X /C "rpm -E %{_host_vendor}"'
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: RPM query for default vendor returned: '1' executing 'cmd.exe /X /C "rpm -E %{_host_vendor}"'
        at org.codehaus.mojo.rpm.RPMHelper.getHostVendor(RPMHelper.java:76)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.rpm.AbstractRPMMojo.checkParams(AbstractRPMMojo.java:892)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.rpm.AbstractRPMMojo.execute(AbstractRPMMojo.java:714)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Below is the pom.xml I am using

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals><goal>rpm</goal></goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <group>Applications/Programming</group>
            <filemode>755</filemode>
            <copyright>LGPL</copyright>
            <mappings>
                <mapping>
                    <directory>target/</directory>
                    <sources>
                        <source><location>lib/</location></source>
                    </sources>
                </mapping>
            </mappings>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Let me know what is missing here?

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728174/cygwin-maven-rpm-segmentation-fault) be related?

Comment: First suggestion would be to use a up-to-date version of [rpm-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/). Furhtermore why not creating RPM's on the appropriate platforms (like Linux) instead of Windows 7.

Comment: I am able to overcome this issue now by installing cygwin. But now even though the build is successful, I don't see .rpm files getting generated instead under target directory rpm folder is created. Can anyone please guide me as I am new to rpm world

Answer (score 13):

The rpm-maven-plugin just calls the operating system `rpm` commands, so you need to run it on RedHat or CentOS where those commands are available. This plugin will not do anything on other operating systems.

Comment: I have installed cygwin on my machine now and running the  following cmd to generate rpm "mvn clean package rpm:rpm". Now the build is success and in the target dir, a new folder named rpm is created with all the necessary files I need. But again there is no .rpm file generated.

Comment: What happens if you run `rpm` from the Cygwin bash shell?  That is exactly what the plugin is doing.

Comment: On hit of rpm I get,  RPM version 4.11.1
Copyright (C) 1998-2002 - Red Hat, Inc.
This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPL

Usage: rpm [-afgpcdLlsiv?] [-a|--all] [-f|--file] [-g|--group] [-p|--package] [--pkgid] [--hdrid] [--triggeredby] [--whatrequires] [--whatprovides] [--nomanifest] [-c|--configfiles] [-d|--docfiles]
        [-L|--licensefiles] [--dump] [-l|--list] [--queryformat=QUERYFORMAT] [-s|--state] [--nofiledigest] [--nofiles] [--nodeps] [--noscript] [--allfiles] [--allmatches] [--badreloc] [-e|--erase=<package>+]
        [--excludedocs]

Answer (score 8):

You need to have the rpm command. Different operating systems may have different ways to to install it. Cygwin is a way to have it in windows. I had the same problem in Ubuntu and solved it by:

```
sudo apt install rpm
```

So depending on the OS/Distribution you may have different ways to install RPM

Comment: Even I am facing the same error on Ubuntu. But I have rpm already installed. The version is RPM version 4.14.2.1. Any idea as to how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Closing this post as the above issue got resolved after installing cygwin on windows.

But even now rpm is not generated. 
I am closing this discussion and opening a new one to discuss on the new issue.

[RPM file not generated using maven rpm plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278968/rpm-file-not-generated-using-maven-rpm-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Is necesary install rpm-build package
yum install rpm-build

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30297602)