# RPM query for default vendor returned: '3' executing '/bin/sh -c rpm -E '%{_host_vendor}''

Tags: java, maven, rpm, rpm-maven-plugin, mvn-repo

I am using Ubuntu 18.
When I try building my maven project with the command: mvn clean install, I am facing the following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.0:attached-rpm (attach-rpm) on project <my_project>: RPM query for default vendor returned: '3' executing '/bin/sh -c rpm -E '%{_host_vendor}'' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.0:attached-rpm (attach-rpm) on project <my_project>: RPM query for default vendor returned: '3' executing '/bin/sh -c rpm -E '%{_host_vendor}''
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: RPM query for default vendor returned: '3' executing '/bin/sh -c rpm -E '%{_host_vendor}''
    at org.codehaus.mojo.rpm.RPMHelper.getHostVendor (RPMHelper.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.rpm.AbstractRPMMojo.checkParams (AbstractRPMMojo.java:892)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.rpm.AbstractRPMMojo.execute (AbstractRPMMojo.java:714)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

The post [Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.0.1:rpm (default-cli) on project inv-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253926/failed-to-execute-goal-org-codehaus-mojorpm-maven-plugin2-0-1rpm-default-cli) suggested installing rpm.
I have installed rpm using the cmd: sudo apt install rpm. Still not able to resolve the error below.
Anyone who has resolved this issue?

Comment: First upgrade your plugin version to most recent one...

Comment: I am having the latest version, <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>

Comment: No you don't.  https://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/

Comment: As I see in the website the latest plugin version is 2.2.0. The build error I am getting is as follows:-
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.2.0:attached-rpm (attach-rpm) on project <my-project>: RPM query for default vendor returned: '3' executing '/bin/sh -c 'rpm' '-E' '%{_host_vendor}''